# pygal data series of different lengths

Tags: python, pygal

How can I plot multiple data series with different number of elements and have them fill the graph along the x axis?

At the moment if I graph a = [1,2,3,4,5] and b = [1,2,3] the b lines only covers half the graph.  Is this possible or do I need to somehow combine the graphs after plotting/rendering them?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it sorted, I was using the wrong graph type